# Java Не правильно преобразовывается строка в дату

Tags: java, дата

У меня есть две строки с датами (на скриншоте это beginDateStr и endDateStr). При попытке преобразовать их в тип Date получается так, что обеим датам месяц устанавливается на январь вне зависимости от того, какой месяц стоит в строке (расчитывается, что дата всегда будет указывать на будущее). Как я могу исправить это и почему так происходит?
[image: Скриншот]

Код:

```
Date beginDate, endDate;
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
beginDate = format.parse(beginDateStr);
endDate = format.parse(endDateStr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mm - в описании формата даты это минуты, вам нужно MM

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Подробнее можно почитать в документации по классу [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)